# Ajuda com SQL para buscar aviões que já fizeram todas as rotas

Tags: sql

Imaginando que são 3 aviões (A,B,C) e 5 rotas e os inserts (A-1; B-2,4,5; C-1,2,3,4,5), pretendo selecionar apenas os aviões que já efetuaram voos em todas as rotas, neste caso o C (C-1,2,3,4,5).

Já experimentei de várias maneiras, mas o SQL devolve todos os aviões que já fizeram pelo menos uma rota (A-1, B-2,4 e C-1,2,3,4,5 ).

O que me falta ou estou a fazer mal?

```
 SELECT a.matricula
  FROM Aviao a  
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT  v.cod_rota
     FROM Voo v 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT r.cod_rota
                        FROM Rota r
                        WHERE a.matricula = v.matricula
                        AND v.cod_rota = r.cod_rota))
```

Estas são as minhas tabelas:

```
Aviao (matricula, nome, data_aquisicao, TipoAviao.cod_tipo) 

Piloto (Tripulante.id, n_aterragens, n_descolagens, n_horas_voo, tipo) 

Habilitado (Piloto.id, TipoAviao.cod_tipo, n_licenca, data_licenca) 

Rota (cod_rota, Aeroporto.cod_aeroporto_ini, Aeroporto.cod_aeroporto_fim) 

Voo (n_voo, data_partida, data_chegada, Rota.cod_rota,

Piloto.id_comandante, Piloto.id_copiloto, Aviao.matricula)
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa. Você diz que quer selecionar avioes que fizeram voos em todas as rotas, e depois fala que o sql seleciona avioes que fizeram qualquer rota. Não faz sentido, é a mesma coisa. Edite sua pergunta e esclareça melhor o que de fato você quer.

Comment: O sql seleciona todos os aviôes que já tenha feito pelo menos uma rota, imaginando que são 5 rotas, quero que selecione apenas os avioes que já fizeram as 5 rotas no total. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Experimenta assim:

```
select a.matricula
from   aviao a
left join (
    select matricula, count(distinct cod_rota) numRotas
    from   voo
    group by matricula
) v 
   on v.matricula = a.matricula
where v.matricula is null                                        -- avioes que nao fizeram qualquer rota
   or v.numRotas < ( select count(distinct cod_rota) from rota)  -- avioes cujo número de rotas efectuadas é diferente/menor que o número total de rotas existentes
```

A lógica é a seguinte:

- o primeiro left join determina, para cada avião, o número de rotas diferentes já efectuadas
- a query irá depois devolver os aviões que ainda não fizeram qualquer voo
- ou os aviões cujo numero de rotas (distintas) já efectuadas é diferente do número total de rotas ( `select count(distinct cod_rota) from rota` )